# Some iterations fail is the estimate still good?

Tags: stata, iteration-methods

0

I am using the csdid command in stata for panel dataset with multiple treatment periods.

When the command is running some of the iterations fail, but I still get an output. I looked in the helpfile for csdid and it states "Each succesful iteration is represented by a ".", whereas an "x" indicates for some ATT(G,T), the estimation failed."

Can I still use the output results or should I consider another estimator?